# Unable to create changelist from Jenkins Perforce

Tags: jenkins, groovy, perforce, jenkins-groovy

how do you create an empty changelist from groovy in the P4 Jenkins plugin?

I saw that by doing this I can create a job

```
def job = p4.fetch('job', 'job000006')
def desc = job.get('Description')
desc = "hello"
job.put('Description', desc)
p4.save('job', job)
```

So I do not understand why the following solution does not work

```
def change = p4.fetch('change','new')
def desc = change.get('Description')
desc = "hello"
change.put('Description', desc)
p4.save('change', change, "-f")
```